# C++ capture forked child cout

Tags: c++, fork, cout

I have the following code snippet:

```
stringstream userOut;
streambuf* old = cout.rdbuf(userOut.rdbuf());

pid_t pid;

if (!(pid = fork())) {

    cout << "hello from child!" << endl;
    exit(0);


} else {
    int status;

    // wait for child to finish
    wait(&status);

    // give cout old buffer back
    cout.rdbuf(old);

    // prints nothing!
    cout << "child content: " << userOut.str() << endl;
}
```

I want to be able to capture and redirect cout from the child process to be used in the parent process, but so far the redirected output it always empty. What could be causing this and are there any available solutions?

Comment: `fork()` creates a copy of the current process, so the child writes to a copy of `userOut`.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the child's output in a similar manner?

Comment: The usual way to connect an output channel of one process to the input channel of another process is a pipe. Thus, parent process could read input from pipe and output to standard output again.

Comment: @jajabarr One way is to use POSIX [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the forked process gets a copy of the stream. So its writing to a copy of the output stream.

Usually, you want to use pipes for that kind a problems.
If you consult `man 2 pipe`, you will find this example at the end :

> The following program creates a pipe, and then fork(2)s to create a
>          child process; the child inherits a duplicate set of file descriptors
>          that refer to the same pipe.  After the fork(2), each process closes
>          the file descriptors that it doesn't need for the pipe (see pipe(7)).
>          The parent then writes the string contained in the program's command-
>          line argument to the pipe, and the child reads this string a byte at
>          a time from the pipe and echoes it on standard output.

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pipefd[2];
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

Comment: To be pedantic, the contents of `stringstream` are not stored on the stack, rather in the heap.